# AWS Dynamodb console simple query using primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple dynamodb table. I am trying to use the AWS Dynamodb console to get the item using the primary key.

I have only 55+ rows in the table. When i am trying to run search query using the primary key, i notice that for few entries it does return the result as expected. And for few it doesn't return the result, even though i can see the item exist in the table.

Request your help, why this is happening. 
 ====
Wanted to share few more inputs. If you see the first picture that has the primary key value existing. but when i query, it gives value not found.

Appreciate if you could update, what am i missing.

[Data exist in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laBpg.png)

[Filter query doesnot give that as the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3uh0.png)

Comment: Dear experts - Appreciate if any update on this please. @IanMeyers - AWS, wanted to get your feedback. thx

Comment: Team - Any feedback on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there's a possibility that you have non-printing characters in your primary key?

Comment: Unfortunately No. Just simple text. Is it something to do with the ReadCapacityUnits ? I am not sure. Need help from SMEs.

Comment: Added the snapshot in the original query.